# Fail to refresh access token in OAuth 2.0 Playground

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground

1. Select custom API profile,email;
2. Exchange authorization code for tokens;
3. Play with v2/userinfo, userinfo requests, everything is OK;
4. Away for a long time, the access token has expired when back, and clicking "Refresh access token" got following error:

   {
     "error_description": "Token has been revoked.", 
     "error": "invalid_grant"
   }

How can this happen? As the note in playground, "refresh tokens never expire".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security measure we are automatically revoking refresh tokens that are generated using the default/test application credentials of the OAuth Playground after a few hours.

If you would like to avoid this you can provide your own application credentials using the Settings menu (top right "cog" icon).